# Saving number 000

Tags: .net, vb.net

When I save a number to my mysql database with a **"000"** in it, it became **"0"** only.

For example, my data is this.

> Name: Daisy Johnson>
>
> Age: 23
>
> **TIN ID: 123-456-789-000**

When I save it in my database it will be like this.

> Name: Daisy Johnson
>
> Age: 23
>
> **TIN ID: 123-456-789-0**

Any suggestions?

```
    Dim sup1 As String = Val(txttin1.Text)
    Dim sup2 As String = Val(txttin2.Text)
    Dim sup3 As String = Val(txttin3.Text)
    Dim sup4 As String = Val(txttin4.Text)
    Dim tinid As String = sup1 + sup2 + sup3 + sup4
    tinid = sup1 + "-" + sup2 + "-" + sup3 + "-" + sup4
```

Comment: `123-456-789-000` is not a number - you cant add or subtract with it and `-` is not a numeral, so it is unclear what you are doing,

Comment: Are you saving the whole text in one column? What is the data type of this column? Could it simply be that your text is truncated because you are exceeding the allowed character length? You will need to show your code.

Comment: Yes I'm saving the whole text in one column. Tha data type of the TIN ID is VARCHAR. @Filburt

Comment: Does it go through some conditioning (i.e. Split(id, "-")) and parse each part as a number, then create a string? "000" parsed as integer would result in 0. Or is your type in SQL varchar(13) ?

Comment: Please end the guessing game and show the *code* used to save the data.

Comment: It seems that you exceeded the allowed length of that field.
To be sure, May you try to save 123-456-789-123 to check. I think the problem isn't with the zeros

Comment: Remove the Val part

Comment: `String.Format` or `String.Join` would be much less gruesome code.  They start as strings, they are saved as strings, so dont convert to numbers along the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```vb
Dim sup4 As String = Val(txttin4.Text)
```

To

```vb
Dim sup4 As String = txttin4.Text.Trim()
```

(for all sup variables)

Val returns a number from a string. See [Val Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9(v=vs.90).aspx)

Even better, if you need the number to have three digits, you could format the string. Val is fine here to tell the formater that it is a number.

```vb
Dim tinid As String = String.Format(
    "{0:000}-{1:000}-{2:000}-{3:000}",
    Val(txttin1.Text), 
    Val(txttin2.Text), 
    Val(txttin3.Text),
    Val(txttin4.Text))
```

So if the user entered "45", it would be formatted to "045", for instance. You should also first perform some validation on the input to make sure that the user actually entered a number in the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments you're using this code:

```
Dim sup1 As String = Val(txttin1.Text)
Dim sup2 As String = Val(txttin2.Text)
Dim sup3 As String = Val(txttin3.Text)
Dim sup4 As String = Val(txttin4.Text)
Dim tinid As String = sup1 + sup2 + sup3 + sup4
tinid = sup1 + "-" + sup2 + "-" + sup3 + "-" + sup4
```

Firstly, Why you're giving a value to `tinid` and you just don't use it then set another value ?

Secondly, the `Val` function converts your expression to `Double`, That's why your zeros are removed.
Your code should look like:

```
Dim sup1 As String = txttin1.Text
Dim sup2 As String = txttin2.Text
Dim sup3 As String = txttin3.Text
Dim sup4 As String = txttin4.Text
Dim tinid As String = sup1 + "-" + sup2 + "-" + sup3 + "-" + sup4
```

Finally, Your question has nothing to do with `mysql`